# MVC Model Binding return Arrays for Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model with the following properties:

```
 public class MyModel{

     public object Name{get;set;}

 }
```

The Name property is rendered as a textbox on an MVC form. When the MVC form is submitted the Name property is set with the type Array[String] with a length of 1 and my value in it. Why does the model binder create the array rather than just setting the property to a string object?

Unfortunately I can't change the return type of the property because this property is in a third party piece of code.

Some more info:

We have two sites, one site binds the property as a string the other site binds it as an Array[String]. Looking at the stack trace both bind events are going through the default model binder. SO the problem we have is what is different about our first environment to our second? Both are using the same assembly versions and config.

Comment: Can you show your `View`?

Comment: This is probably just the behavior of the DefaultModelBinder. You could probably customize it by implementing your own IModelBinder that does what you want for model properties of type object.

Comment: After further investigation (a lot of decompiling and swearing) we have discovered that there is a DI container hidden in the third party code that isn't resolving the field binder correctly. Thanks to those of you read and commented on this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can override behavior of Default model binder in following way. Custom model binder gives you ability to changes form default object types to type of your choice.

As You want object to be changes to string type. First need to write the implementation of your choice in which IModelBinder helps.

```
public class CustomBinder : IModelBinder
{
  public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
    HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
    string name = request.Form.Get("Name");    
    return name
  }
}
```

Then we application will hit Application_Start() before Posting the data we need to register it.
By adding definition for model binder into Application_Start()

```
 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyModel), new CustomBinder());
```

Then Use the custom binding at Post method where you will get forms data

```
 public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomBinder))] MyModel model)
```